# Run PHPUnit rather than Pest

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, pestphp

I have a project with a mixture of tests wrtten in Pest and regular PHPUnit Test Classes. There is a lot missing from Pest for package developers and its just simpler to use the PHPunit for areas where Pest can't help. Pest is great and I can use it 90% of the time but the odd thing is missing. When I run `php vendor/bin/phpunit` I get:

```
Pest\Exceptions\InvalidPestCommand 

Please run [./vendor/bin/pest] instead.
```

I can't see any options to bypass Pest here according to the docs for CLI.

Has anyone had any success in running these side by side.

Note: I am aware that Pest will run PHPUnit TestCases but a lot of annotations provided by PHPUnit simply can't be used with Pest. e.g. `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses`

Comment: I'm seeing this too.. glad its not just me